# Submit Data Using HTML Form Web Part

Tags: web-part, custom-list

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I've created a fill-able form using the HTML web part in SharePoint 2010 and I want to submit the data to a list. I've created the form and the corresponding list. Is there a way to connect this form to the list to submit using SharePoint Designer 2010 or through the web interface? I don't want to use Infopath or VS. Thank you.

Comment: I've noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to your previous questions. Accepting valid answers helps other users quickly identify viable solutions. If a question you have asked was not answered, but you have resolved it, you can answer it yourself to help future visitors to the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could submit the data via JavaScript from the client object model JS library.
[COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701783%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You need some way of hitting the API, whether it is from C#(VS) or JavaScript.